# kapacitor metrics database missing in influxdb

Tags: metrics, influxdb, kapacitor

I have kapacitor 1.3.1 and influxdb 1.2.4 running on my machine. Though i have enabled kapacitor to send its stats, i dont see _kapacitor database in influxdb.
What am i missing here?
kapacitor.config:

```
hostname = "localhost"
[stats]
  # Emit internal statistics about Kapacitor.
  # To consume these stats create a stream task
  # that selects data from the configured database
  # and retention policy.
  #
  # Example:
  #  stream|from().database('_kapacitor').retentionPolicy('autogen')...
  #
  enabled = true
  stats-interval = "10s"
  database = "_kapacitor"
  retention-policy= "autogen"

[[influxdb]]
  # Connect to an InfluxDB cluster
  # Kapacitor can subscribe, query and write to this cluster.
  # Using InfluxDB is not required and can be disabled.
  enabled = true
  default = true
  name = "localhost"
  urls = ["http://localhost:8086"]
  username = ""
  password = ""
  timeout = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** What am i missing here?

**A:** You got the first step right by enabling the stats functionality in `Kapacitor`. The next thing you need to do here is to bounce the `Kapacitor` engine this is so that stats are getting written into its internal database periodically.

Now the catch is that you'll need to also define a TICK script to pull the stats out from `Kapacitor`'s internal database, then you can choose what you want to do to it, manipulate the data and write it back to an `InfluxDB` or raise `alerts`.

Example:

```
var data = stream| from().database('_kapacitor').retentionPolicy('autogen')
data
  |log()
   .prefix('Kapacitor stat =>')
```

After you got your tick script going. You'll have to do the usual, like installing it into `Kapacitor` then enable it.

```
kapacitor define test -type stream -tick test.tick -dbrp _kapacitor.autogen
```

There is a catch here. You need to specify the retention policy that you have specified in the `config` or otherwise it won't know where to look for the data. In this case it is `_kapacitor.autogen`.

```
test   stream    disabled  false     ["_kapacitor"."autogen"]
```

Next you enable the stream task.

```
kapacitor enable test
```

**Output:**

> [test:log2] 2017/07/26 00:49:21 I! Kapacitor stat =>
>   {"Name":"ingress","Database":"_kapacitor","RetentionPolicy":"autogen","Group":"","Dimensions":{"ByName":false,"TagNames":null},"Tags":{"cluster_id":"c80d02c0-8c51-4071-8904-1583164e90ec","database":"_internal","host":"kapacitor_stoh","measurement":"tsm1_cache","retention_policy":"monitor","server_id":"82a2d589-db45-4cc5-81b0-674cb80737ac","task_master":"main"},"Fields":{"points_received":4753},"Time":"2017-07-26T00:49:21.75615995Z"}

Comment: Thank you much. It worked!! I had to create the database _kapacitor in influxdb and rest all was smooth. This is on my mac.
The same I tried on a centos box, it didn't work. I will check it anyway

Comment: If you can't get it to work on Centos using the same step you did with the Mac then I would suggest you raising it with the `kapacitor` guys. Works on Ubuntu. Will appreciate if you can mark this as answered since it works.